# How async tasks and cursors lead to memory leak?

Tags: android

Would like to have a deeper understanding of the same on how async task on orientation changes can lead to memory leak. I have done my bit of research but couldn't find a precise solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when the orientation changes, Android framework destroys the activity (garbage collects the memory allocated) and creates a new one.

Now say you are running an `AsyncTask` which holds a reference to an `Activity` class object and the orientation changes. Here, Android framework would not be able to destroy the activity (as it is still referenced by your `AsyncTask`) while a new one will be created in its place. This is one of the ways how memory leaks happen.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of AsyncTask, you pass the reference of activity in it using "this" or context. If you rotate the device when asyncTask is working, activity gets recreated and previous instance is still available to AsyncTask which cause memory leak.

Best practice is to check yourActivity.this.isFinishing() in postExecute and do not update the UI. You can cancel the asyncTask with cancel() method.